# Using inline styles on a Styled component?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I'm using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) in a React project an I can't find documentation anywhere on whether or not a styled component will accept inline styles on the "style" property. For example:

The styled Text component

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

type TextProps = {
  content: string
  className?: string
  id?: string
}

const UnstyledText: React.FC<TextProps> = ({ className, content }) => {
  return (
    <span
      className={className}
    >
      {content}
    </span>
  )
}

const Text = styled(UnstyledText)`
  font-size: '1vw'
  line-height: '2vw'
`

export default Text
```

The Text component in use:

```
import styles from './index.module.css'
import Text from '../ui/atoms/Text'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles['home-page-container']} style={{ display: 'block' }}>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        <img
          src={'/_next/static/media/image.jpg'}
          alt={'background'}
          width="100%"
        />
        <Text
          style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '10%', top: '20%' }}
          content="Some text i want to position"
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          padding: '20%',
          maxHeight: '75vh',
          backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '10%', top: '20%' }}` inline styles are not recognized in the browser.

Instead I'm forced to add a "style" prop to the styled component, then spread the object onto the span like so:

```
const UnstyledText: React.FC<TextProps> = ({ className, content, style }) => {
  return (
    <span className={className} 
    style={{ ...style }}
    >
      {content}
    </span>
  )
}
```

If I don't do this, I have to wrap the styled component in a div and add my styles to that div, adding bloat to my project.  I don't want to add a "style" prop to every component, nor a wrapper div any time I need additional styles on a component.  There has to be a way around this.

Thoughts?

Comment: Side note: `style={{ ...style }}` could be written as `style={style}` if you're not adding anything to it

Answer (score 0):

This is because props (like `style`) are not automatically passed to all children components.

The React-y way to pass data deeply is to use [contexts](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context). These contexts could be sets of styles.

Additionally, at times you may be able to use CSS variables set on the parent (which are inherited by the children in the DOM) to avoid having to use React to pass down styles through all of your components or via contexts.